# Multicontext Core Data: Deleting objects from the childContext

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm using two `NSManagedObjectContext` in my application. One is the childContext and an another one is the mainContext. Whenever there is a sync operation, I'll download the data from the server using the childContext in the background thread and merge it into the mainContext in the mainThread.

If there is no data to sync to the server ((i.e.,) if a user isn't added any data), I'm resetting the childContext and deleting the objects from the childContext from one of the entity and making an API call and inserting the objects received from the server to the same entity into the childContext and merging into the mainContext at the end of the operation.

The problem is the deleted data removed from the mainContext but, the DB (.sqlite) file size is increased every time, when I try to re-do the sync. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: The second paragraph of your question is very confusing.  You should edit and try to make it more understandable – what you are doing, why, and what the problem is.

Comment: I have edited my question, let me know. If you need further info.

Comment: Thank you.  Now I understand it is the file size you are concerned with.  Please give some numbers – maybe number of objects in the store and file sizes before and after the deletion.  Also, note that Core Data produces three SQLite files, with extensions .sqlite, .sqlite-shm, and .sqlite-wal.  These are all part of the "database (DB)".  What about the -shm and -wal files?

Comment: Initially, the SQLite file is 838KB and no. of objects present is 5903. If I re-sync again, the SQLite file is same but SQLite-wal file size is increased to 1.6MB and the total no. of objects present is 11801. If redo the sync again, the SQLite file size is 3.6MB but the SQLite-wal file is 4.3MB and the total no. of objects present is same.

Comment: Is that increase in the number of objects from 5903 to 11801 expected?  How are you measuring the number of objects?  As far as the file sizes, those several megabytes are not significant enough to worry about yet.  SQLite does tricks with its -shm and -wal files to increase speed and reliability, and the file sizes are not always proportional to the information stored.  Let's concentrate on managing your object count.